# How to solve this error 36.0.0 is not a valid SDK version Options are 35.0.0, 34.0.0,33.0.0 unversioned

Tags: react-native

I am working on a react native project When I type npm start the it is showing this error, please tell me how to solve this error 36.0.0 is not a valid SDK version Options are 35.0.0, 34.0.0,33.0.0 unversioned

Comment: is this an expo project?

Answer (score 0):

Follow the steps:

1. delete node_modules folder
2. run command in the project directory

```
npm install
```

this command will scan packages from `package.json` and run `npm start`